# Drawbacks of ext js

Tags: extjs

I am would like to use ext js in a new application for my client, 
Ext js had lot of widgets that i can leverage and MVC framework.  Can anyone throw some light on the drawbacks of ext js?.
What are the things that i need to keep in my mind while using ext js?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been using ext js for more than a year in a complex large-scale application.
These are some of the drawbacks that I have come across with Ext JS:

1. I have observed relatively slow loading in our application. The library has big size. A lot of JS code has to be loaded during pre-initialization of the application. (need to use sb3 ext js SDK tool to consolidate all your ext js  source files for improving performance)
2. Finding CSS selectors is tedious and not extensible to other non ext js UI’s.  I have spent a lot of time figuring out the correct definitions for CSS selectors.  I don't think it's documented anywhere either.  So i just can't seriously customize quickly.  Even if we end up writing custom CSS for Ext, we will not be able to reuse this CSS for other UI technologies such as HTML,
3. Availability of Ext developers (resources) are rare.  Whereas, there are good amount of jQuery talent

Ext's Data visualization/3D Graphic visualization is not up to the standards that can meet all the needs (stocks charts, candle stick charts and so on). High charts/d3 would be viable option here.

Ext js is a single page application, you need to implement url hashing for multi-page interaction(browser back and front button interaction)

Answer (score 1):

1. $400 per developer, though cheaper than building/integrating jQuery widgets I would say.
2. Not crawlable by Google, though if you are behind a login, doesn't matter.
3. It's a bitch to theme. Sencha introduced their Neptune theme like 2 years ago, and it still barely works, and that's with their own engineers working on it.
4. Has some irritating bugs and sucks to get model associations working.

Still worth it though.

Answer (score 0):

First thing Ext js is good for SPA(single page applications).

Major Drawbacks of ext js:
1) Slow in IE 9 and blow
2) Memory leakage 
3) Lots of DOM objects
4) SKIN customization is hard. should know CSS or SCSS
5) always have to cleanup variables.

Answer (score 0):

I am using extjs and sencha touch for more than 4 years. What can I say is that (almost) none of the above are really true.
Possible drawbacks:

1. Learning curve might be a little larger if one has no experience with oop.
2. Complex relations between models are a little bit tricky.
3. Is not free but...

   If you are planning to build up a enterprise application to run in browser I wouldn't know another choice.